Langchain: Output of one chain as input for another using LCEL
I've started working with Langchain to get a feel of it and a lot of the videos seem outdated. After some research I learned about LCEL being used as the other methods seem to be deprecated.
In my code I'm trying to use the output of one chain as the input for another but it doesn't seem to work.
def main():
    # chain1
    prompt1 = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
        ('system', "Answer in less than 20 words."),
        ('human', '{task}')
    ])
    chain1 = prompt1 | model | {'rep1': StrOutputParser()}

    # chain2
    prompt2 = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
        ('system', "You're drunk."),
        ('human', 'Translate {rep1} to {lang}'),
    ])
    datamap = {
        'lang': RunnablePassthrough(),
        'rep1': RunnablePassthrough(),
    }
    chain2 = datamap | prompt2 | model | {'rep2': StrOutputParser()}

    # Combine chains
    allchain = chain1 | chain2

    # Pray to cthulu for the right response
    response = allchain.invoke({
        'task': 'Good morning',
        'lang': 'french'
    })

    print(response)

The result I'm getting is
response: {'rep2': "It looks like you've already translated the text into the same text. "
                   'Is there anything else you need help with?'}

I wrote this off the bat so I understand if it's not optimized in any way but I'm curious to also know how this would would be done in production.
